# Multi-line equation with image

Tags: graphics, equations

I am trying to write an equation in which the right hand side is an image and the left hand side a mathematical expression. The only problem is that the expression is too long and it has to be separated in more than one line. I'd like to have a final result in which the mathematical expression is centered with respect the image. The closest output I got is with this code:

```
\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image}}} =

\begin{split}

\frac{i k_g}{\Lambda}\;\delta^{a_1a_2}\bigg[\eta^{\nu\sigma}\Big(k_1^\mu        k_2^\rho+k_1^\mu k_1^\rho\Big)+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\Big(k_1^\nu k_2^\rho+k_1^\nu   k_1^\rho\Big)\\
&\eta^{\nu\rho}\Big(k_1^\sigma k_2^\mu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\mu\Big)+\eta^{\mu\rho}\Big(k_1^\sigma k_2^\nu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\nu\Big)\\
-\eta^{\rho\sigma}\Big(k_1^\mu k_2^\nu+k_1^\nu k_2^\mu\Big)-k_1\cdot k_2\Big(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}\Big)\bigg].

\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But this is the output[image: Output I got]

As you can see the expression is not really aligned with the image and the second line is partially out of the page.
How can I properly solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please provide us with a MWE?

Answer (score 3):

It *can* be done with `split`.  **Edit:** Ooops! I had forgotten to `\smash[b]` the picture…

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}



\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \smash[b]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image}}}}
                    = {}&
            \frac{i k_g}
                {\Lambda}\;\delta^{a_1a_2}\biggl[\eta^{\nu\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\mu        
                k_2^\rho+k_1^\mu k_1^\rho\Bigr)\\
            &+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\nu k_2^\rho+k_1^\nu k_1^\rho\Bigr)
                \cdot \eta^{\nu\rho}\Bigl(k_1^\sigma k_2^\mu
            +k_2^\sigma k_2^\mu\Bigr)\\
            &+\eta^{\mu\rho}
                \Bigl(k_1^\sigma k_2^\nu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\nu\Bigr)\\
            &-\eta^{\rho\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\mu k_2^\nu+k_1^\nu k_2^\mu\Bigr)-
                k_1\cdot k_2\Bigl(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}+
                \eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}\Bigr)\biggr].
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

I have chosen different points where to break the equation, IMHO they look much better.  Also note that I have replaced `\Big` with `\Bigl` or `\Bigr` as appropriate, and the same for `\bigg`.  Finally, note how the alignment point is specified.

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

## Addition

The OP clarified that a different output was wanted, namely

[image: Desired output]

In my humble opinion, this looks poorer than the output produced by the above code; in any case, it doesn’t pose any particular problem either:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}



\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
    \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image}}} =
        \begin{aligned}
            &\frac{i    k_g}
                {\Lambda}\;\delta^{a_1a_2}\biggl[\eta^{\nu\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\mu        
                k_2^\rho+k_1^\mu k_1^\rho\Bigr)\\
            &+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\nu k_2^\rho+k_1^\nu k_1^\rho\Bigr)
                \cdot \eta^{\nu\rho}\Bigl(k_1^\sigma k_2^\mu
            +k_2^\sigma k_2^\mu\Bigr)\\
            &+\eta^{\mu\rho}
                \Bigl(k_1^\sigma k_2^\nu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\nu\Bigr)\\
            &-\eta^{\rho\sigma}\Bigl(k_1^\mu k_2^\nu+k_1^\nu k_2^\mu\Bigr)-
                k_1\cdot k_2\Bigl(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}+
                \eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}\Bigr)\biggr].
        \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `aligned`; the picture can be vertically centered with `gathered`, which is less cumbersome than `\vcenter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{gathered}
=
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\frac{i k_g}{\Lambda}\delta^{a_1a_2}\bigl[
  \eta^{\nu\sigma}(k_1^\mu k_2^\rho+k_1^\mu k_1^\rho)\\
&+\eta^{\mu\sigma}(k_1^\nu k_2^\rho+k_1^\nu k_1^\rho)
  \eta^{\nu\rho}(k_1^\sigma k_2^\mu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\mu)\\
&+\eta^{\mu\rho}(k_1^\sigma k_2^\nu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\nu)
 -\eta^{\rho\sigma}(k_1^\mu k_2^\nu+k_1^\nu k_2^\mu)\\
&-k_1\cdot k_2(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}+
  \eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho})\bigr].
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is with `adjustbox`, if you wish a different relative placement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\setlength{\adjboxvtop}{1.2\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
=
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\frac{i k_g}{\Lambda}\delta^{a_1a_2}\bigl[
  \eta^{\nu\sigma}(k_1^\mu k_2^\rho+k_1^\mu k_1^\rho)\\
&+\eta^{\mu\sigma}(k_1^\nu k_2^\rho+k_1^\nu k_1^\rho)
  \eta^{\nu\rho}(k_1^\sigma k_2^\mu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\mu)\\
&+\eta^{\mu\rho}(k_1^\sigma k_2^\nu+k_2^\sigma k_2^\nu)
 -\eta^{\rho\sigma}(k_1^\mu k_2^\nu+k_1^\nu k_2^\mu)\\
&-k_1\cdot k_2(\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}+
  \eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho})\bigr].
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

[image]